# Java Constructor not working

Tags: java, class, constructor

I'm making an application which reads from a file and then uses each line as the parameters to create an object, ultimately making an array of objects.
Problem is, the constructor doesn't appear to be working and I can't for the life of me figure out why. The section of code not working can be summarised as:

```
this.arrayOfObjects[number] = MyObject(oData[1],oData[2],dataSet);
```

In the code above, we can regard 'number' as an integer intialised to 0, 'oData[1]' as a string, 'oData[2]' as a string and dataSet as an array of integers.
This line of code shows the error: 
"The method MyObject(String, String, int[]) is undefined for the type ObjectData"
However I have a constructor which pefectly matches this, and if I allow Eclipse to apply a 'quickfix' of creating a constructor itself, it still doesn't work.
For reference, my constructor in the MyObject class is:

```
public MyObject(String string, String string2, int[] dataSet){...}
```

Thank you if you can help, I will remain online to clarify at all if needed.

Edit: the first line of code is in the constructor for another class, whether or not this affects the behaviour i'm not sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Constructors are invoked with a `new` keyword otherwise they're treated like methods:

```
this.arrayOfObjects[number] = new MyObject(oData[1],oData[2],dataSet);
```

Comment: I can't believe I overlooked such a simple mistake. All part of the learning curve I guess, thank you!